# Yii2 mongodb query select query

Tags: php, mongodb, yii

For example, I have [this MongoDB](http://i1224.photobucket.com/albums/ee371/dat162/mongodb_dataview_zpsxt901slf.png):

In yii2, I want to write a query to find an `email = 'abc'`. I have this code:

```
 $query->select([])->from('Post')->where(['Comments.Email' => 'abc']);
```

But it does not work; please help me, as I'm beginner in Yii2 and MongoDB.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
$res = $collection->find(["comments.email"=>"abc"]);
$rows = $res->toArray();
```

From documentation:
https://www.yiiframework.com/extension/yiisoft/yii2-mongodb/doc/api/2.1/yii-mongodb-collection#find()-detail

Answer (score 2):

You can try this

```
Document::find()->where(["comments"=>["document"=>["email"=>"abc"]]])->all();
```

Answer (score 0):

You can do that but using this query below,

```
 $order = (new Query)->select([])->from('post')->where(['email' => 'abc'])->all();
```